# Distribution of sum of exponential variables with different parameters

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

We have $k$ independent random variables with exponential distribution ($T_1, T_2, \ldots , T_k$), parameters of random variables are ($\lambda,\frac{\lambda}{2},\frac{\lambda}{3},\ldots,\frac{\lambda}{k}$), what is the distribution of new variable $T = T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_k $

Comment: are they independent ?

Comment: @Canardini Oh sorry I forgot it, yes they are.

Comment: Sometimes when people write of "the exponential distribution with parameter $\alpha$" they mean $\displaystyle e^{-x/\alpha} \left(\frac{dx} \alpha\right) \text{ for } x\ge 0,$ so that $\alpha$ is the expected value, and sometimes they mean $\displaystyle e^{-\alpha x} (\alpha\,dx) \text{ for } x\ge0,$ so that $1/\alpha$ is the expected value.  Which do you have in mind here? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for your comment, the second one so when I say $T_i$  has exponential distribution ($Exp(\frac{\lambda}{i})$) I mean $e^{-\frac{\lambda}{i}T_i}$

Comment: I do not see any pattern when using moment generating functions. Do you know that if the exponentials are identically distributed, the sum is the Gamma distribution?

Comment: Thanks @Therkel Yes, I see that Gamma distribution with parameters ($k$,$\lambda$), but unfortunately when parameters are not identical, the Gamma distribution cannot be used.

Comment: Correct. Indeed when I attempted with the mgf approach, I got an expression with the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). I am afraid you are not going to be able to recognize any of our usual distributions.

Comment: @Therkel Recognizing an usual distribution is not important, but anything related to them or a closed form distribution without integral I think is a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot recognize any closed form when convoluting either. I hope someone will post an answer, if they do!

Comment: Oh, thank you @Therkel  it's the kind of you, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the main result [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mb13434/sumexp.pdf) applied to the sequence $\lambda, \lambda/2,...,\lambda/k$, which for the general case states that

$$ h_{X_1,.,X_n}(x) = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_{i} \right] \sum_{j=\
1}^n \frac{e^{-\lambda_i x}}{\prod_{k \neq j}^n(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)} $$

Comment: Has anybody found any information with regards to the CDF equivalent of this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You could use convolution to calculate the distribution of two independent variables:

Assume $X$ follows $f(x)$, $Y$ follows $g(y)$, then $Z=X+Y$ follows

$$f_Z(z)=\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y) \, dy.$$

Following this logic, you just do a serial integrations, then you would get the result.

Comment: Can you please tell me about doing serial integration for 3 variables when we have $W = X + Y + Z$?

Comment: So you just first get distribution $X+Y$, then use this obtained distribution to  do the integration with $Z$. Two steps.

Comment: This answer is correct as far as it goes, but it doesn't attempt to say whether the particular pattern in the sequence of parameters leads to some pattern in the distribution of the sequence of sums.