# Distribution of sum of exponentially distributed variables with arbitrary rates

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Consider independent random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, each of them exponentially distributed with parameters $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. Let us consider the sum $Y= X_1 + \ldots + X_n$.

(1) In the case where all the rates are equal ($\lambda_i = \lambda$ for all $i$), we know that the distribution is a *[Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)*:
$$
f_Y(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.
$$
(2) In the case where all the rates are different $(\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j $ for all $i,j$), we can also calculate the distribution of $Y$. This time it is given by the *[hypoexponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution)*:
$$
f_Y(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \prod_{j\neq i} \frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j - \lambda_i} \right) \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i t},
$$
where the product is over all $1 \leq j \leq n$, $j \neq i$. For an induction proof see [Ross](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124079482).

(3) Now consider the case in which some rates are equal to others but they are not all equal, i.e. the number of unique rates is between $2$ and $n-1$. **Is there a general formula for the distribution of the sum in this case?**

I tried approaching the problem by computing convolutions and trying to find a pattern in the distributions. For example, for two variables $X_1, X_2$ I would calculate $f_{X_1+X_2}(t) = \int\limits_{0}^{t} f_{X_1}(s) f_{X_2}(t-s) ds$, and then do this iteratively for more and more variables where some but not all rates are similar. **From the results I obtained I came up with the following conjecture**:

Assume that there exist $i,j$ such that $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$ and that there exist $m,n,$ such that $\lambda_m \neq \lambda_n$. Define $m$ as the number of distinct rates, $2 \leq m \leq n-1$. Define $n_j$ as the number of variables with rate $\lambda_j$, $1 \leq n_j \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$. Hence the system is specified by $(m, n_1, \ldots, n_m)$ and rates $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m)$. Then the distribution of $Y$ is given by
$$
f_Y(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left[ \prod_{j\neq i} \left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j - \lambda_i}\right)^{n_j} \right] \lambda_i^{n_i} \left[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_i} \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \right] e^{-\lambda_i t},
$$

I was not able to proof this by induction or verify it in some other way than by checking results for a small number of variables. **Could you prove or disprove the conjecture I made above**?

*Linked question*

[Distribution of sum of exponential variables with different parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055840/distribution-of-sum-of-exponential-variables-with-different-parameters): a similar question, but it only considers a special case with parameters $(\lambda, \lambda/2, \lambda/3, \ldots, \lambda/n)$, which belongs to case (2) above. I would like to know the general case for arbitrary $\lambda_i$'s.

Comment: I see in the wiki page you quoted, there is a general case in the bottom. Is that the case you want?

Comment: Actually, yes, there's a formula at the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution. I don't know if it is similar or different from my formula (it looks quite different). However, it comes without explanation or reference, so I would still appreciate an explanation or link to a reference where this is worked out.

Answer (score 3):

The general formula you are looking for is on equation (1.1) on the paper of [Smaili et. al (2016)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610926.2014.930910). On that paper they review examples of your 3 cases plus one more intermediate case.